# Docker: no such file or directory

Tags: python, docker

Пытаюсь запустить в контейнере баш скрипты для запуска контейнера celery и flower. В Dockerfile копирую все файлы в контейнер, соотвественно должна быть папка docker с баш скриптами по пути /docker/*.sh, но у меня ошибка что нет их. Где у меня ошибка в докер файле или как посмотреть какие файлы в контейнере находятся не запуская при этом сам контейнер? (т.к. контейнер выдает ошибку и не запускается так что не могу сделать в терминале контейнера ls).
Код из Docker Compose:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  'db':
      image: postgres:15
      container_name: booking_db
      env_file:
        - .env-non-dev
      ports:
        - 5432:5432

  redis:
    image: redis:7
    container_name: booking_redis

  booking:
    image: booking_image
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: booking_app
    env_file:
      - .env-non-dev
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    command: ['/booking/docker/app.sh']
    ports:
      - 7777:8000

  celery:
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: booking_celery
    command: ['/booking/docker/celery.sh', 'celery']
    env_file:
      - .env-non-dev
    depends_on:
      - redis

  flower:
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: booking_flower
    command: ['/booking/docker/celery.sh', 'flower']
    env_file:
      - .env-non-dev
    depends_on:
      - celery
```

[image: Код Dockerfile и архитектура приложения]

Ошибка:

```
[+] Running 5/4
 - Container booking_db      Running                                                                               0.0s
 - Container booking_redis   Running                                                                               0.0s
 - Container booking_app     Created                                                                               0.0s
 - Container booking_celery  Recreated                                                                             0.1s
 - Container booking_flower  Recreated                                                                             0.1s
Attaching to booking_app, booking_celery, booking_db, booking_flower, booking_redis
booking_app     | exec /booking/docker/app.sh: no such file or directory
booking_celery  | exec /booking/docker/celery.sh: no such file or directory
booking_celery exited with code 1
booking_app exited with code 1
booking_flower  | exec /booking/docker/celery.sh: no such file or directory
booking_flower exited with code 1
booking_db      | 2024-01-09 22:44:25.121 UTC [27] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
booking_db      | 2024-01-09 22:44:25.143 UTC [27] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 3 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.008 s, sync=0.003 s, total=0.023 s; sync files=2, longest=0.002 s, average=0.002 s; distance=0 kB, estimate=0 kB
```